# C# Linq- How to get distinct collection from a collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following collection:

```
public IList<Emp> EmpList()
{
    IList<Emp> empList = new List<Emp>();
    empList.Add(new Emp() { Id = 1, Name = "abc1" });
    empList.Add(new Emp() { Id = 1, Name = "abc2" });        
    empList.Add(new Emp() { Id = 2, Name = "abc3" });
    empList.Add(new Emp() { Id = 2, Name = "abc4" });
    empList.Add(new Emp() { Id = 4, Name = "abc5" });
    return empList;
}
```

I wants to get distinct records based on Id from the `EmpList()` collection. I mean first row, third row and last row from the `EmpList()` collection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit-`var empList = emp.EmpList().GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First());`
This query is working fine for the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this, from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com/)

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
return empList.DistinctBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Is there any alternate solution because I don't want to use MoreLinq.

Comment: @mnmnmnmnm you can paste this code as extension method and use it like I suggested. To use extension method you need to have static class: EnumerableExtensions and put there this method

Comment: !wudzik, Yes I got it but here i have pasted sample but in real scenario I have to implement it in the Vb.Net, and I guess Vb.net does not support extension method :(

Comment: @mnmnmnmnm Huh? Of course VB.Net supports extension methods.

Comment: @mnmnmnmnm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx look here for extension methods in vb

Comment: @wudzik,, thanks for letting me know..yes i tried and found that vb.net also supports extension method. Thanks :)

Comment: But meanwhile I have written var empList = emp.EmpList().GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First()); and now its also working fine :)

Comment: @mnmnmnmnm of course you can use `groupby` to do this :) but personally I prefer `DistinctBy`, your choice :)

Comment: +1 -i literally picked this little extension method up a few weeks back and use it with such joy now. my varsion is slightly different and uses linq, rather than loops but is functionally identical.

Comment: This is kind of a lazy alternative to writing an equality comparer and using the [provided overload of `Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx), with the bonus side effect that you *know* this will always return the *first* item per key, while `Distinct` makes no such guarantee.

Answer (score 4):

```
var q = from e in empList
        group e by e.Id into grps
        select grps.First();
```

Comment: It's incomplete because the question provides no more info.

Comment: People why do you down vote with no reason????

Comment: Yes Its not compiling :(

Comment: +1 Come on, the typo is *soooo* obvious. It's just missing an *s* on `grp`. Can't people think nowadays? Grouping and taking the first element of each group is an easy way to do a "distinct-by".